# Disable the Health-analyzer rule [InfoPath form library forms cannot be filled out in a Web browser]

Tags: infopath, health-analyzer

In my SP2010 Server farm I have this rule violation warning in Health Analyzer.
I don't need this feature to be enabled [filling out InfoPath form library forms in a Web browser]

I know that recommended way is to install a Shared State Service Application and bind it to the Web Application.
But again I don't need it.

Operations guys complain me about this warning in HA (they like seeing no errors/warnings)

What could be wrong if I just disabled this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The health analyzer rules are there to notify you of potential issues with your farm.  If one of the rules doesn't fit your environment, you can by all means disable that rule.